# Separate string column by row efficiently

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, rowwise

I'm trying to separate a string column into two pieces based on chopping up the string.  It's best illustrated with example below. `rowwise` does work, but given the size of the data.frame, I'd like to use a more efficient method. How can I avoid using `rowwise`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

#make data
a <- "(1, 10)"
b <- "(10, 20)"
c <- "(20, 30)"

df <- data.frame(size = c(a,b,c))

# Goal is to separate the 'size' column into 'lower' and 'upper' by
# extracting the value contained in the parens and split by a comma.
# Once the column is split into 'upper' and 'lower' I will perform 
# additional operations.

# DESIRED RESULT
  size     lower upper 
  <fct>    <chr> <chr> 
1 (1, 10)  1     10
2 (10, 20) 10    20
3 (20, 30) 20    30

# WHAT I HAVE TRIED

> #This works... but too inefficient
> df %>%
+   rowwise() %>%
+   mutate(lower = str_split(size, ",") %>% .[[1]] %>% .[1] %>%
+            str_split("\\(") %>% .[[1]] %>% .[2])
  size     lower
  <fct>    <chr>
1 (1, 10)  1    
2 (10, 20) 10   
3 (20, 30) 20   

> # I'm not sure why this doesn't work
> df %>%
+   mutate(lower = str_split(size, ",") %>% .[[1]] %>% .[1] %>%
+            str_split("\\(") %>% .[[1]] %>% .[2])
      size lower
1  (1, 10)     1
2 (10, 20)     1
3 (20, 30)     1

> #Not obivous how to use separate (tidyr)
> df %>%
+   separate(size, sep=",", c("lower", "upper"))
  lower upper
1    (1   10)
2   (10   20)
3   (20   30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't state your goal explicitly, but it seems like you want to extract the first number from a string. This is easy with `stringi::str_extract_first_regex`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(df$size, "[0-9]+")
# [1] "1"  "10" "20"
```

So in your case,

```
df %>% mutate(lower = as.numeric(stri_extract_first_regex, size, "[0-9]+"))
```

You can extract all numbers with `stri_extract_all_regex`.

---

Based on your edits:

```
df$nums = str_extract_all(df$size, "[0-9]+")
df$lower = as.numeric(sapply(df$nums, `[[`, 1))
df$upper = as.numeric(sapply(df$nums, `[[`, 2))
df
#       size   nums lower upper
# 1  (1, 10)  1, 10     1    10
# 2 (10, 20) 10, 20    10    20
# 3 (20, 30) 20, 30    20    30
```

---

Another way to go is to get rid of the parens and whitespace and then use separate:

```
df %>%
    mutate(just_nums = str_replace_all(size, "[^0-9,]", "")) %>%
    separate(just_nums, into = c("lower", "upper"))
#       size lower upper
# 1  (1, 10)     1    10
# 2 (10, 20)    10    20
# 3 (20, 30)    20    30
```

The regex pattern `"[^0-9,]"` matches everything except numbers and commas.

Comment: I updated my question with a more clear definition of what I want as a result. I can't figure out how to make what you propose here to work.

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I wanted, and it keeps it all neatly in `dplyr` for subsequent operations. (with the use of the `stringi` package)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with decimals.. For example if the first row was `(0.1, 10)` this code returns 1 and 10, instead of 0.1 and 10.

Comment: You can modify the regex to include decimals. Make the replace pattern `"[^0-9,\\.]"`, or the extract pattern `"[0-9\\.]+"`. Alternatively, if your strings are as shown, you could make the replace pattern `"[\\(\\) ]"` to replace only parens and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

For rowwise operations, I prefer data.table.

Try this

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

#make data
a <- "(1, 10)"
b <- "(10, 20)"
c <- "(20, 30)"

dt <- data.table(c(a,b,c))
dt[, lower := tstrsplit(V1, ",")[1]]
dt[, lower:= stri_replace_all_regex(lower, '\\(', '')]

dt
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you might want to show OP how to use this without data table in case they are unfamiliar with the syntax. (Also you have a typo, "tstrsplit".)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `data.table` but I will be stringing together a lot of `dplyr` via the `%>%` so if there is a native `dplyr` way to do it that would work better I think. Your solution does work though so I will look to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `tidyr::separate` after removing both `(` and `)` from the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(size = gsub("\\(|)","",size)) %>%  # Both ( and ) has been removed.
  separate(size, c("Min", "Max"), sep = ",")
#   Min Max
# 1   1  10
# 2  10  20
# 3  20  30
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Here is my explanation for two approach, one is similar to yours:

In the first code, I have used unnest_tokens from tidytext package, which can split words on a different rows, since you want to extract the first item before the comma(I have assumed it basis your example, although you should mention it). I have choosen the first row basis this by using filter command.

In the second code, I have used the regex (note you can also use here `str_replace` also). Here I am using map(since the items returned by str_split is a list) to iterate the returned items and pass each by gsub, which can replace the regex matched with the back referencing items. Also to select only the first item, I have used [[1]] in the end of gsub.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)
df %>% 
    unnest_tokens(lower,size, token="words",drop=F) %>% 
    filter(row_number()%%2==T)

df %>% 
    mutate(lower = map(str_split(df$size, ","), function(x)gsub("\\((\\w+)","\\1",x)[[1]]))
```

**Output**:

```
   #       size lower
   # 1  (1, 10)     1
   # 2 (10, 20)    10
   # 3 (20, 30)    20
```

In case you want to extract both the terms before and after the commas, you can use `extract` function as well.

```
tidyr::extract(df, size, c("lower", "upper"), regex= "\\((\\w+),\\s+(\\w+)\\)")
```

**Output**:

```
  #   lower upper
   # 1     1    10
   # 2    10    20
   # 3    20    30
```